# How to Implement nested_form gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am trying to implement nested form in rails with the help of nested_form gem. I want the nested fields to be displayed in tabular format. Can any one help me out?

Following is my view file:

```
<%= nested_form_for @invoice,url: invoices_path,method: :post do |f| %>

<div class="row form-inline">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <ul id="sortable" class="append-table">
                <li class="table-responsive has-dropdown invoice-append">
                <div class="table items">
                    <div class="table-head">
                        <div class="th"></div>
                        <div class="th">#</div>
                        <div class="th">Name</div>
                        <div class="th">Description</div>
                        <div class="th">Quantity</div>
                        <div class="th">Item Price</div>
                        <div class="th">Total Price</div>
                        <div class="th">Taxable</div>
                        <div class="th"></div>
                        <div class="th"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="table-body ui-sortable">
                      <%= f.fields_for :invoice_line_items do |ff| %>
                        <div class="tr item">
                          <div class="td handle-cell">
                           <div class="handle ui-sortable-handle"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="td display-order-cell">
                              <div>
                                <div class="display-order">1</div>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="td">
                                <div class="form-group name-container">
                                    <span class="twitter-typeahead" style="position: relative; display: inline-block;">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control typeahead name prevent-enter tt-hint" maxlength="200" disabled="" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; border-color: transparent; box-shadow: none; background: none 0% 0% / auto repeat scroll padding-box border-box rgb(255, 255, 255);">
                                      <%#= ff.text_field :name, class: "form-control  typeahead name prevent-enter tt-input", placeholder: "Name",style: "position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent;" %>
                                      <input type="text" name="item0[name]" id="name" value="A" placeholder="Name" class="form-control typeahead name prevent-enter tt-input" maxlength="200" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent;" dir="auto">
                                      <pre aria-hidden="true" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden; white-space: nowrap; font-family: azo-sans-web, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; word-spacing: 0px; letter-spacing: 0px; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; text-transform: none;"></pre>
                                      <span class="tt-dropdown-menu" style="position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0px; z-index: 100; display: none;">
                                      <div class="tt-dataset-invoiceItemTemplatesAutocomplete"></div>
                                    </span>
                                  </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="td">
                                <div class="form-group description-container">
                                  <%= ff.text_area :description, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Description" %>
                                    <!-- <textarea name="item0[description]" id="description" placeholder="Description" class="form-control description" maxlength="1000" style="overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: none; height: 60px;"></textarea> -->
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="td quantity-cell">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <%= ff.text_field :quantity, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Qty" %>
                                    <!-- <input type="text" name="item0[quantity]" id="quantity" value="5" placeholder="Qty" class="form-control quantity prevent-enter" size="5" maxlength="10"> -->
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="td original-price-cell">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon">₹</div>
                                    <%= ff.text_field :price,class: "form-control", placeholder: "Item Price"%>
                                    <!-- <input type="text" name="item0[original_price]" id="original_price" placeholder="Item Price" class="form-control original-price money-only prevent-enter" size="9" maxlength="9"> -->
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="td price-cell">
                                <label class="price-display"></label>
                                <%= ff.hidden_field :total_price,class: "form-control price money-only" %>
                                <!-- <input type="hidden" name="item0[price]" id="price" placeholder="Price" class="form-control price money-only" size="9" maxlength="9"> -->
                            </div>

                            <div class="td is-taxable-cell">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <%= ff.check_box :is_taxable %>
                                    <label class="optional" for="remember"></label>
                                  </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="td remove-cell">
                            </div>

                            <div class="td save-invoice-item-template-cell">
                                <a href="#" class="js-save-as-invoice-item-template">Save to Use Again</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <% end %>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add Item", :invoice_line_items, class: "btn btn-default" %></p>
          <!-- <button  type="button" class="btn btn-default add-item">Add Item</button> -->
        </div>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

This structure adds the nested fields outside the table structure. How to add it within `<div class="table-body">`?

Answer (score 1):

can u please explain about your form to be nested?

```html
  (inside your parent form model)
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :your_nested_form
   (inside your parent form)
 = nested_form_for(@your_parent_form) do |f|
```

Comment: https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form ..clear guide for implementing nested form is in this link